# maven: With one pom.xml I am creating jar and tar.gz but don't want to deploy jar

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-deploy-plugin, maven-install-plugin

With one pom.xml first I am creating a jar file with maven-jar-plugin and signing it with maven-jarsigner-plugin, second I am creating a tar.gz package with maven-assembly-plugin, copying jar file and other necessary files into tar.gz. Just because only tar.gz package is enough for me, I want only tar.gz package to deploy remote repository. When I run the "mvn deploy" command, both the jar and tar.gz packages are being deployed. Are there any method for not to deploy jar file to remote repository.

Comment: So hard to read. Please use bold text and so on. Thanks

Comment: Please share your pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

I tried your suggestion. It is not working for maven-deploy-plugin but it is working for maven-install plugin. Here is the relative part of my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-file</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-dev.tar.gz</file>
                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <packaging>tar.gz</packaging>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <classifier>dev</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy-file</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://repo/artifactory/snapshots</url>
                <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-dev.tar.gz</file>
                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <packaging>tar.gz</packaging>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <classifier>dev</classifier>                    
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

maven-install-plugin is installing only tar.gz file to local repository but maven-deploy-plugin deploying both tar.gz and jar files to remote repository. I think this behaviour can be maven-deploy-plugin's bug.

Answer (score 0):

By default the Maven Deploy plugin [will deploy all the artifacts attached to your project or module](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/index.html), i.e. both your *.jar* and *tar.gz* file.

> `deploy:deploy` is used to automatically install the artifact, its pom and the attached artifacts produced by a particular project.

What you can do is skip the `deploy:deploy` goal and configure a personalized `deploy:deploy-file` goal, such as:

```
<build>
    ...
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip> <!-- Skip the default deploy -->
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <!-- Deploy our tar.gz -->
                <execution>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.tar.gz</file>
                        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <packaging>tar.gz</packaging>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
    ...
</build>
```

You'll have to configure `<file>` to use your generated *tar.gz* file.

Comment: As far as I see, deploy-file requires providing the remote repository id and url separately from what is given in distributionManagement and there's no easy way to alternate between the snapshots and releases repos.